# How to use selenium / python to have all drop down arrows in a website show their content

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to get text from a website for a personal project but the text I need is stored after several layers of drop down boxes.

i.e. (V is a down arrow that is clickable to reveal more)

**Product Group (V)**

**Product name (V)**

**Protection Ratings (V)**

**Description of rating**.........................**5 Star Rating**.................**Target number**

So from this I want the Product name, Description of rating and target number

So far I have been able to get the Product name by first getting the elements that match the down arrow

```
element_list = []
for items in range(0,13):
    try:
        temp = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="grouping_{}"]/a/div/div/span'.format(items))
        element_list.append(temp)
    except:
        continue
```

and then I went through the list and clicked each down arrow using a 0.5 second break so that the website could do the action and refresh

```
for i in range(1,len(element_list)): 
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_list[i]).click(element_list[i]).perform()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

this revealed each product in the product grouping and I can then get the product name using the CSS tag

```
product_titles = []
titles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.seat-title')
for title in range(len(titles)):
    product_titles.append(titles[title].text)
```

But now I need to essentially click on each product then the Protection ratings link to reveal the final rating. Is there an easier way than manually finding the elements to click and then clicking. So far most things on this website don't appear to have a CSS ID and I have been using the XPATH to find the right elements but figure there should be a faster way to get what I want.

The website I am trying to scrape is
https://www.childcarseats.com.au/find-and-compare-child-car-seats#/results

Comment: Can u send us the website URL?

Comment: please add url and full code

Comment: I only see the one dropdown on the far right. Also, what is target number? The price? And what is rating description? Does one need to visit the actual product urls in each case?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. There is only one drop down button. Then you have to click on the product name to open the next layer. After that you need to click on the protection or ease of use names to reveal their respective ratings. I am after the name of the individual rating (i.e. Maintaining its structural integrity in frontal and side impacts (critical feature)) and the score (i.e. 12/12). I basically want the ratings for each product at the individual rating level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check before browsing the DOM, is to check if the data is not passing through an XHR request (F12 -> Network -> XHR). Here it's the case.

The second thing to do is to explore the data branches. Look at: https://www.childcarseats.com.au/api/v1/child_car_seats/filter_data/retrieve?_format=json and https://www.childcarseats.com.au/api/v1/child_car_seats/seat_extra/retrieve/1108 to get an idea of what the data structure looks like.

The first link refers to all the items on the page. The second link allows you to get all the details on a particular item, here the object '1108'.

The following code :

```
import requests as rq
# the following two lines allow to remove warnings created by "verify=False".
import urllib3 
urllib3.disable_warnings()

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"}
url = "https://www.childcarseats.com.au/api/v1/child_car_seats/filter_data/retrieve?_format=json"
resp = rq.get(url, headers=headers, verify=False).json()

seats = resp["seats"]


url_2 = "https://www.childcarseats.com.au/api/v1/child_car_seats/seat_extra/retrieve/"
data = []
for (i, seat) in enumerate(seats):
    nid = seat["nid"]
    product_name = seat["product_name"]
    resp2 = rq.get(url_2 + nid, headers=headers, verify=False).json()
    resp2 = resp2["tests"]

    for k1 in resp2.keys(): # through rating schemes keys
        for k2 in resp2[k1].keys(): # through seat types keys
            for k3 in resp2[k1][k2].keys(): # through test types (protection / ease of use)
                for k4 in resp2[k1][k2][k3].keys(): # through test names

                    item = resp2[k1][k2][k3][k4][0]
                    score, score_max = item["score"], item["score_maximum"]

                    data.append({"product_id":  nid, 
                                 "product_name":product_name,
                                 "rating_scheme": k1,
                                 "seat_type": k2,
                                 "test_type": k3,
                                 "test_name": k4,
                                 "test_score": score,
                                 "test_score_max": score_max
                                })
    print("%s/%s" % (i+1, len(seats)))
```

get you data you want ('data' variable).

Note : I set 'verify=False' 'cause I get some trouble with SSL certificates. Try without if u want.

Comment: where is the rating for each test?

Comment: in data, "test_score". if u want decimal score, its just : score / score_max

Comment: E.g. If you look at Distributing loads to the dummy's torso in frontal impact for Nuna Pipa Klik (tested with ISOFix) CF-06-001AU where is the rating of 1?

Comment: OK, I understand, The product name is not exactly stored the same way in the API and on the website. You refer to product NID 1110. So the name is "Pipa Klik", not "Nuna Pipa Klik".

Comment: Then, the score = 2.8, maximal_score = 8 so decimal_score = 0.35. Scale on 5 : 5 * 0.35 = 1.75 ; so calculated_score = 2 (round up) et stars (complete stars) = 1.

Comment: + for the explanation

Comment: Just for future reference how/where did you get the URLs for the website API?

Comment: Go on the page, open F12 -> Network -> XHR, reload the page, you get "retrieve?_format=json" line. Next click on a seat row on the webpage and you get a new line with ID of seat.